# Unity crashes on startup on my Linux machine

Tags: crash

My problem: I've installed Unity Engine over the Unity Hub on my Linux machine (Zorin OS 16 Core - Ubuntu based Linux Distribution) but every time I try to start it it just crashes before the UI loads.

I already tried to install different versions of the Editor (2020.3 and 2021.?) but it didn't work. I also tried to reinstall the Unity Hub but that solved the problem neither.

Here are the Crash logs from Editor.log:

```
[LAYOUT] About to load UserSettings/Layouts/default-2021.dwlt, keepMainWindow=False
GLX Extensions: GLX_ARB_create_context GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_ARB_get_proc_address GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_EXT_buffer_age GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_EXT_import_context GLX_EXT_no_config_context GLX_EXT_swap_control GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap GLX_EXT_visual_info GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_INTEL_swap_event GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer GLX_MESA_query_renderer GLX_MESA_swap_control GLX_OML_swap_method GLX_OML_sync_control GLX_SGIS_multisample GLX_SGIX_fbconfig GLX_SGIX_pbuffer GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group GLX_SGI_make_current_read GLX_SGI_swap_control GLX_SGI_video_sync
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
Unity: ../../src/xcb_io.c:260: poll_for_event: Zusicherung »!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost« nicht erfüllt.
Caught fatal signal - signo:6 code:-6 errno:0 addr:0x3e8000018de
Obtained 17 stack frames.
#0 0x007f6c84ec83c0 in funlockfile
#1 0x007f6c84d0503b in gsignal
#2 0x007f6c84ce4859 in abort
#3 0x007f6c84ce4729 in (Unknown)
#4 0x007f6c84cf6006 in __assert_fail
#5 0x007f6c86070643 in _XFreeX11XCBStructure
#6 0x007f6c860706ed in _XFreeX11XCBStructure
#7 0x007f6c860709ea in _XEventsQueued
#8 0x007f6c860739dd in _XGetRequest
#9 0x007f6c8606ee04 in XCreateWindow
#10 0x007f6c857b7d46 in gdk_x11_window_set_user_time
#11 0x007f6c8578ae7d in gdk_window_ensure_native
#12 0x007f6c857b8f78 in gdk_x11_window_get_xid
#13 0x0055bfe5507038 in GUIView::CreateGfxWindow()
#14 0x0055bfe550a5a1 in GUIView::SetWindow(ContainerWindow*)
#15 0x0055bfe3a4aba0 in GUIView_CUSTOM_Internal_SetWindow(ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*)
#16 0x0000004193c36c in (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.GUIView:Internal_SetWindow (UnityEditor.GUIView,UnityEngine.ScriptableObject)
Launching bug reporter
QApplication: invalid style override passed, ignoring it.
Available styles: Windows, Fusion
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QObject(0x15c7a10), parent's thread is QThread(0x12c53b0), current thread is Thread(0x171f6e0)
```

And here a screenshot:
[Unity Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfyd0.png)

I really don't know what to do. Any ideas?
Would be really nice. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to go to the Unity folder in the terminal and run it with a couple of prefix:

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=4.5 MESA_GLSL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=450 ./Unity
```

UnituHub could be in `~/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.3.30f1/Editor/Unity` or in a similar folder according to your version.

Source: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-crash.1240999/